# Aligning an absolute positioned element to the middle of a parent element

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

If I have something along the lines of:

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And have the first `<ul>` positioned relatively, while the second `<ul>` is positioned absolutely, is it possible to align the **middle** of the second `<ul>` to the middle of the parent `<li>`, and keep it responsive?

To be clear, this is not `vertical-align`, or in any way related to it.

Comment: Can (or does) the second ul have a width?

Comment: Would it matter? The width would either be set in the CSS, or by however long the text is, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep an absolute positioned element which has not a fixed `width` at the middle (horizontally) of its parent, I'd suggest:

```css
#child {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/hTeFw/)**

Comment: Almost got it. Initially, the child ul had its left side aligned to the left side of the parent li. Your change has now aligned the middle of the child ul to the left of the parent li, and it remains that way for all screen sizes/browser widths/resolutions. Progress!

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle or sample to demonstrate the issue in action?

Comment: Give me a few minutes. I need to filter out the relevant CSS in my file. I've got it so compacted and combined, it would make people with OCD jealous!

Comment: Strange. I can't get the fiddle to work. Eventually, I just grabbed everything and pasted it in, and it still didn't work.

Comment: It's hard to say what's going wrong. But if you could create a simple online demo instead of grabbing the code from your project...

Comment: I've just messed with my code a bit more, and modified your additions. Since I have multiple drop downs, I assigned each child ul a class, and added just the transform to it, so that I could adjust the widths accordingly. That seems to be a decent enough solution. I removed the left:50%; completely. Didn't look like it was doing anything at any value. I think this was the solution I needed. Thanks.

Comment: I've just tested this on Chromium in Linux, and saw that the left side of the drop down was aligned to the left side of the parent <li>. Compatibility issues? Any other alternatives?

Comment: @Hiigaran Did you use the vendor prefix? `-webkit-transform`

Comment: I use the -prefix-free script to eliminate that need, but I could give it a shot.

Comment: Yep. That worked. Strange, though. It should have been added via the script.

Answer (score 0):

Does this contain only wording or images as well?

Try this:

```
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

Comment: For the purposes of this question, I left the content out to make it simpler to read, but yes, it would contain text

Comment: Regarding your edit, that doesn't work. It makes no difference.